# Converting a responsebody in okhttp3 to a list of custom objects using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

In my code, I take all the data base of my friend's server and print it in a log. 
Now what I want to do is to take the jsons he sends me, and convert these jsons into a list of custom objects I called User.

This is my response code. The log in the end prints in my log all of my friend's DB.

```
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call,@NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            int i;
            int size;
            try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()){
                if(!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code" + response);
                Headers responseheaders = response.headers();
                for(i = 0, size = responseheaders.size(); i < size; i++){
                    Log.d("TAG", responseheaders.name(i) + ": " + responseheaders.value(i));
                }
                Log.d("TAG","Mazal's DB -----> "+ responseBody.string());
            }
        }
```

**This is my custom object**:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public User(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is what I get in the response body I mentioned before: http://prntscr.com/i69gx8 (The response is much longer... couldn't fit everything in the picture)

I want to use Gson, and I want to take the jsons from the response, take the users and passwords and turn them into a list or an arraylist of objects I called User.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Retrofit` call should be generalised with `User` class like `Call<User>` then in `onResponse` callback you will receive not raw type like now, but generalised `Response<User>`. Then use `response.body()` method to get your `User` object.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my bad, thought you are using retrofit client over OkHttp. 
In your case you should deserialise received response to your `User` object like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type userType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>(){}.getType();
List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), userType);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your User object. BTW I recommend you use Retrofit over OkHttp. Here is its [page](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: What is a Retrofit call?

Comment: One correction to the snippet by Anton:  
there should be `response.body().string()`  
instead of  
`response.body().toString()` - that prints just Java Object hashcode.